# What are horizontal and vertical track pitches?

Tags: vlsi, asic

I was experimenting on OpenLANE with Sky130 PDK and below is the `tracks.info` file. I learned from a workshop that the values pertain to the track pitches as indicated below.

[image: tracks.info]

But I'm confused on what horizontal/vertical track pitch mean. For example on the sample image below:

- Is the horizontal track pitch is the `Metal1 pitch` since that is the distance between the horizontal wires?
- Or is it the`Metal2 pitch` since that is the distance of the grids on the horizontal plane?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the horizontal pitch is the Metal 1 pitch, because Metal 1 is used for horizontal wiring. Of course, the word "horizontal" only makes sense when you are the human designer looking at a layout....the chip itself has no sense of "horizontal" or "vertical".